# how to solve write data definition operations in java?

Tags: java, sql

I am trying to execute the query below:

```
    String sql="create or replace view toprecords as select * from(select directory_name,file_name,sum(value) from tfidfvalues where directory_name =? group by(directory_name,file_name) order by(sum(value)) desc) where rownum<=10";
                        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                        stmt.setString(1, directory_names.get(x));

                        stmt.executeUpdate();
```

When I execute it in oracle it works fine but when I try to implement it in java it shows the following error:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01027: bind variables not allowed for data definition operations
```

SO how to overcome this exception?

Comment: *"When I execute it in oracle it works fine"* ... how, exactly, are you using a prepared statement "in oracle" ?

Comment: the error is pretty clear, you can't bind variables in `DDL` operations

Comment: @BrianRoach In oracle means the query works fine but shows error when embeded in prepare statement

Comment: [Why cannot I use bind variables in DDL/SCL statements in dynamic SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25489002/1461424)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says it all, you can't use bind variables in DDL operations.

What you will have to do is create your view without the `where` clause, and instead apply the filtering when you query your view.

Comment: Or just modify the SQL String in Java. Though that can lead to a bigger problem if the input is untrusted, obviously.

Comment: @Brian: True, but then you are also just hacking your way around the fundamental issue with the approach.

Comment: @Keppil I dint exactly get what you are trying to say. Can you please elaborate how should I modify my query

Comment: @Subodh: I assume you are going to query the view you are creating here later on. So, instead of using the `where` clause when creating the view, you use it later when querying your view. This will give you the same result.

Comment: @Keppil wouldn't that make the view possibly very large? (which may be undesirable if this action is run very frequently...)